# ASP.Net Browser Definition Files to solve IE10 javascript postback issues

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-10

I have a website built using Framework 2.0. In IE10 the javascript postbacks for link buttons don't work. To try to solve this I have followed Scott Hanselman's instructions http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx  and added an updated ie.browser definition file to the App_Browsers folder but this has had no effect. However I have other similar websites on the same web server that now do postback successfully in IE10 after I added the ie.browser file to those project's App_Browsers folder.

I have tried an IISReset and I have also recycled the App Pool but no luck.

Does anybody have any ideas what the issue may be? Thank you.

Comment: Did you upgrade to Framework 4.5? IE10 is supported by it (and you should still be able to run on 2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to get to solve this issue by re-building and re-releasing the site and then adding the browser definition files afterwards. I had spotted a browser definition dll file in the bin folder which had come from my local build - so I'm guessing this had been overuling any other amends I was making.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to run aspnet_regbrowsers after installing the hotfix to register the new definitions in the GAC. Not sure if that part just failed when the installer ran, or if I just didn't restart the server after...(clumsy me)...but after running this command, we're smooth sailing!

here's a link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229858(v=vs.80).aspx

After that I was able to remove the App_Browsers folder hack :)